# show article ID in the url when open article (a href)

Tags: php, jquery, sql

when i click this part a href=".$row['id']." my accordion slides open and article is visible but i when i open this part i want also that the article id is shown in the url
so index.php?id=id and so on, i'm new to php so what do i have to add to this code
to get it work?

```
session_start();

require_once("inc/connection.php");
mysql_select_db("nieuws");

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.acc_container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers
//On Click
$('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { //If immediate next container is closed...
    $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); //Remove all .acc_trigger classes and slide up the immediate next container
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
}
return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
});
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Verwijderen" /> <p style="font-size:12px;">selecteer een artikel</p>
$query="SELECT id,datum,titel,artikel FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo ("<div id=\"artikeltitel\" align=\"center\">
    <div id=\"containerdatum\">".$row['datum']."</div>
    <div id=\"containertitel\">".$row['titel']."</div>
    <div id=\"container3\" style=\"font-size:12px;\">".$row['id']."
    <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox\"  value=\"".$row['id']."\"       />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class=\"container\" align=\"center\">
    <h2 class=\"acc_trigger\"><a href=".$row['id']."> &#187; </a></h2>
    <div class=\"acc_container\">
    <div class=\"block\">".$row['artikel']."</div>
    <div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"http://www.zpb-polonez.be/user.php\" data-num-    posts=\"10\" data-width=\"678\" style=\"margin-top:2px;\"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ");
}
</form>
```

Comment: If you want to change URL but not reload the page, the way to do is using JS hash router. It would look something like this : index.php#id/5

Comment: ok.. but what do i have to do then?

Comment: You need to include JS file or library that has hash routing and set up some code(routes). Backbone.js is easy to use but it has much more functions besides routing so it may be a little too big. There are plain hash routing libraries, but I don't know which to recommend. They are not very complicateted to set up

Comment: isn't it easier to do something like _GET id.. just don't quit understand how to add and let it work